# Вычислить произведение 1, 3 и 6 положительных элементов

Tags: python

У меня не правильно работает программа, предположим я задаю на входе список состоящий из положительных и отрицательных элементов пусть `arr = [5 7 8 -2  6 8 -5 4 -7 7 8 9]` на выходе я получаю результат

> ```
> Индексы элементов: 3 8 16    
> 7 * 2 * 5 = 70
> ```

то есть у меня получается не соответствие индексов и перемножаются не те элементы:

```
arr = input("Введите список:")
arr = list(arr)
N = len(arr)
i = j = 0
i1 = i3 = i6 = -1
while i < N:
    if arr[i] > '0':
        if j == 1:
            i1 = i
        elif j == 3:
            i3 = i
        elif j == 6:
            i6 = i
            break
        j += 1
    i += 1

if i6 > 0:
    print("Индексы элементов:", i1, i3, i6)
    mult = int(arr[i1]) * int(arr[i3]) * int(arr[i6])
    print("%d * %d * %d = %d" % (int(arr[i1]), int(arr[i3]), int(arr[i6]), mult))
```

Прошу объяснить в чём здесь ошибка, ещё лучше если вы покажите верный вариант программы с функцией `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(arr[i]) > 0:
    ...
```

Comment: большое спасибо)

Comment: @Noob_Prog Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

На Python решения с использованием индексов элементов не идиоматичны. Предпочтительны декларативные операции со списками.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

arr = map(int, input("Введите список:").split())
arr_positive = (x for x in arr if x>0)
arr_target = [x for n, x in enumerate(arr_positive, 1) if n in [1, 3, 6]]
mult = reduce(mul, arr_target, 1)
print(f'{" * ".join(map(str,arr_target))} = {mult}') # -> 5 * 8 * 4 = 160
```